# System.Uri doesn't work with specific symbols

Tags: c#, path, uri, .net-assembly

I've found a problem when trying to get relative path from Codebase using Uri.

```
var codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
var path = new Uri(codeBase).LocalPath;
```

The problem is, that my workspace is located in *.../ dev / C# / workspace /...* Windows allows making folder name like "*C#*", but System.Uri doesn't understand that and cut everything after "*#*" symbol.

I know that *Codebase* just start from "*file:///*", that's why I can avoid this problem by using

```
var path = codeBase.Substring(8);
return Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;
```

but I think there is a more elegant solution. Don't you know it?

P.S. I don't want rename my folder, cause it's difficult to make all my TFS project working. Please, don't offer any other `Assemblies` or `AppDomain` methods for getting path - only `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Codebase` is working for me.

UPD: May be I can use something like this:

```
var uri = new Uri(codeBase);
var path = uri.LocalPath + uri.Fragment;
```

Is this a better approach?

Comment: what do you ultimately want to get the path to? To the executing assembly? To the bin dir of the web application? There may be a better way if you can edit you question to add what it is you want to get

Comment: I have to know path to bin dir of web application. 

When I trying to use `Assembly.GetAssembly().Location` it returns "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\538d6292\\93f9f073\\assembly\\dl3\\...".

As far as I know, using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` for manage filesystem is a bad approach.

`Assembly.GetExecutiongAssembly().CodeBase` returns just what I need. My question is only - how to avoid problems with specific symbols in Uri? Or how to make it better then just delete "file:///" by using Substring(8)?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: No, that's return another path. Only Codebase is working when using it in Web project.

Comment: ok, you missed that piece of information out of your question :)

Comment: Sorry) Add it to P.S.

Answer (score 0):

Solve my task using this: System.Web.HttpRuntime.BinDirectory

But the question - How to work with Uri and specific symbols? is still open